# Enter Key is working only once

Tags: android

I have a pos device in that pos having hardware keyboard to handle enter key . But the problem is it is working only once. If I am pressing the enter key again it is not working. I am using the following code

```
 amount.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
     public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {      
         if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){

             //my own logic 

         }
```

Comment: Point of sale like card swiping machine in shopping malls

Comment: what do you return "true" or "false" in method?